# Lazarus: How to check if file is in use?

Tags: pascal, lazarus, file-access, file-in-use

I need to check if a file is in use before I try to get access to it. Is there way to do it in Lazarus environment?

Comment: `try...except` construct is not good enough for you?

Answer (score 2):

Open the file with `FileOpen(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareExclusive)` and check the result.

**Update** (thanks to Ken White's comment). This is not the direct answer to your question as `FileOpen` actually *gets* access to the file, but you shouldn't perform the check and then open the file, otherwise you'll get a race condition. You should open the file and then check if the open succeeded.

Opening a file with `FileOpen` and accessing the file through its handle may seem unfamiliar. You can achieve the same goal when opening a file with e.g. `Rewrite` inside a `try-except` block. I am not sure about Lazarus, but in Delphi using `try-except` with high-level file routines requires explicit resetting IOResult in case of exception (put `SetInOutRes(0)` into `except` section), otherwise the following file operation fails.

Comment: Certainly. I should add to my answer that the test should be performed at the same time as getting access, otherwise there will be a race condition. There are other ways like opening a file inside try-except block. Using `FileOpen` just gives an exception-free way to perform the check.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. You try to open it, and handle the exception if and when you can't.

Checking to see if it's in use first serves no purpose.

```
Your code to see if it's in use says it's not
--->>> Another app opens the file, locking it
Your code to open file fails
```

Instead, use a normal `try..except` block:

```
try
  FS := TFileStream.Create(YourFileName, fmOpenReadWrite, fmShareExclusive);
  // Code to use file here
except
  // Handle failure to access file
end;
```

Comment: Or use $I+/I- and check ioresult if your I/O is not stream based.